# Кто-то знает, как загружать в CDeditor5 фотографии?

Tags: reactjs

Cуть в том, что у меня задача сделать поле WYSIWYG (я выбрал в качестве редактора "CDeditor" (вот например как в stackoverflow, где я сейчас на данный момент пишу. На React я его загрузил, работает, но загрузка фотографий нет, я уже весь инет облазил как это сделать, но нифига не нашел, я в тупике, может быть кто-то подскажет как сделать загрузку фотографий? Буду очень благодарен!!! Официальную документацию CDeditor читал, честно скажу, все равно там я особо не понял как это релизовать